# Why load address works different on words and labels with strings?

Tags: mips

​Hi,

I just had a quick question. Let's say I have 2 labels string and word with string being a label associated with a string and word being an actual word with a 32 bit integer stored in it. Now let's say I use a syscall to print string using the label string and I use load address with register a0, it will print the string. However why doesn't it print the address, since this is load address. On the other hand if I do the exact same thing but instead of using the string label I use the word label I am now instead going to print the actual address. I was wondering why it works this way.

Thanks for your time

Varun G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting syscalls. You issue a certain syscall to do different things.

To print a string you issue a `syscall` 4 (`$v0` = 4). This service prints the string pointed by the address given in `$a0` which you should previously load.

To print an integer you issue a `syscall` 1 (`$v0` = 1). This service prints the integer stored at `$a0`. This integer may be seen as an address if you have loaded it with `la` pseudoinstruction.

So if you have the following snippet:

```
.data
str: .asciiz "hello!"

.text
  la $a0, str
  li $v0, 1
  syscall  # This will print the starting address of the string
  li $v0, 4
  syscall  # This will print the contents of the string pointed by label str
```

it will print the address of the beginning of the string and also its contents.

Comment: Ok I got it. It was a matter of understanding the syscalls. So if we're using syscall 4 we're going to print what's stored inside the address pointed to by a0 and if we're using 1 we're going to print what's stored on inside a0.